# Computing the direct sum of free abelian groups $(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} )/ \langle (2,1)\rangle = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

This came up in an algebraic topology class today, as I wasn't able to follow the explanation as to why the LHS and the RHS are equal. I suspect I might be missing some background in algebra.

The explanation provided was along the lines of mapping a generator $(n,\overline{m})\mapsto 2m+n \mod 4$, where $\overline{m}$ means $m\mod 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is in two steps, where the second step is again divided into two steps. Define the homomorphism $$f:\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z_2\to\Bbb Z_4$$by $f(n,\bar m)=2m+n$ and do the following:

1. Show that $f$ is surjective (easy)
2. Show that the kernel is $\langle (2,\bar 1)\rangle$ by

   - showing that $\langle(2,\bar1)\rangle$ is contained in the kernel (easy)
   - showing that the kernel contains $\langle(2,\bar1)\rangle$ (slightly tricky)

Comment: Not that trickier

Comment: But where do you get $f(n,\overline{m}=2m+n)$ from?

Comment: $f$ surjective: we need to show that $0,1,2$ and $3$ have pre-images. Taking $\overline{m}=0$ and setting $n$ equal to, respectively, $0,1,2,3$, that's what we get.

Comment: $\langle (2,\overline{1}\rangle$ maps to a multiple of 4, so it's in $\ker f$. If we set $2m+n=0$, then $n=-2m=2m$ (last equality follows because we're working in $\mathbb{Z}/4$, and so if $m=\alpha,n=2\alpha$. So the kernel contains $\langle (2,\overline{1})\rangle$.

Comment: The actual idea for exactly what $f$ should be comes from observing that $f(0,\bar1)$ must be either $0$ or $2$. No matter which we choose, we therefore need to use the first component to reach the odd numbers, which means that $f(1,\bar0)$ must be $\pm1$. It really doesn't matter which one we choose. However, we now have the choice for $f(0,\bar1)$. If we send it to $0$, then the kernel becomes $\langle(4,\bar0),(0,\bar1)\rangle$, and if we send it to $2$, then the kernel becomes $\langle(2,\bar1)\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks Arthur. Although how would you know that the direct sum is $\mathbb{Z}/4$ in the first place (and hence observe that $f(0,\overline{1})$ must be either $0$ or $2$)?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt It comes from observing that given an element $(n, \bar m)\in\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/2$, you can find another element $(n',\bar m')$ such that $n'=0$ or $n'=1$, with $(n,\bar m)-(n',\bar m')\in\langle(2,1)\rangle$. It's simply$$n'=\cases{0&if $n$ is even\\1&if $n$ is odd},\quad\bar m'=\cases{\bar0&if $n-n'$ is divisible by $4$\\1&if $n-n'$ is not divisible by $4$}$$and from there you can see that the quotient has (at most) four elements, and also that the element $(1, \bar 0)$ has order $4$, which means that it _has_ to be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/4$.

Comment: I suppose for the $\overline{m}$ cases you meant "if $\overline{m}-\overline{m}'$ is divisible by 4"?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt What I meant was $$\bar m'=\cases{\bar m& if $n-n'$ is divisible by $4$\\\bar 1+\bar m& if $n-n'$ is not divisible by $4$}$$Note that $n-n'$ always is even.